# HttpWebRequest resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"] is null

Tags: c#, cookies, webrequest

Update 1:
Screenshot of post/get headers: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/getpost.png

I'm looking for help with a web request. The purpose of the request is to log in to a site and retrieve the Set-Cookie header. I'm grateful for any help!

I'm trying to log in to a site and retrieve the cookie value using the code below. However, the Set-Cookie header is always null:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string formUrl = "https://account.guildwars2.com/login";
    string formParams = string.Format("email={0}&password={1}", "xxx", "xxx");
    string cookieHeader;
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
    req.Referer = "https://account.guildwars2.com/login";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
}
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with redirects, because in the C# application, the response-uri is "https://account.guildwars2.com/login?redirect_uri=/download"

**Response headers Chrome**

- Content-Length:0
- Content-Type:text/html
- Date:Sat, 29 Sep 2012 15:07:30 GMT
- Location:download
- Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- Set-Cookie:s=60B845F0-4E22-4A4B-890B-F3B885CEF9AE; Domain=guildwars2.com; Path=/; Version=1
- X-Powered-By:ARR/2.5

**Response from C# application**

- Content-Length: 7344
- Content-Type: text/html
- Date: Sat, 29 Sep 2012 15:42:44 GMT
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
- X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5

Comment: I think you need to set httpWebRequest.CookieCollection to new CookieCollection before sending, might have misstyped that not using VS atm.

Comment: I tried req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); but nothing gets added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `HttpWebRequest` automatically follows HTTP redirection responses, which prevents you from capturing the `Set-Cookie` header in the original response. To disable this behavior, set [`AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) to `false` before sending the request:

```
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try retrieve the cookie using this way:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

CookieCollection cookieCollection = cookies.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);
```

Comment: Thanks, but empty cookie collection. I'm starting to think it has something to do with redirects. When I debug in google it first POSTs to the login site with a status 303 (redirect) and then GETs the download site with a status 200 (OK).